# Laravel - whereHas last relation is = 'manual'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a model Lead which 'belongsToMany' Status through lead_has_status table.

What I want is to get all the Leads where the last (current) status of that lead is 'manual'.

I've tried this

```
$leads = Lead::whereHas('statuses', function ($query) use ($q) {
  $query->where('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
})->get();
```

But since the Lead still has it's old statuses linked to it, it returns every Lead that at some point had Status 'manual'. But I only want the Leads where current status is 'manual'. So I want to do something like

```
$leads = Lead::whereLast('statuses', function ($query) use ($q) {
  $query->where('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
})->get();
```

Or

```
$leads = Lead::whereLast('statuses', function ($query) use ($q) {
  $query->latest()->first()->where('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
})->get();
```

(I know this it not the way to do it, it's simply to express what I'm trying to do)

I hope the question makes sense, I am super confused right now.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no built-in eloquent function that gives you this kind of behaviour. If you would like to solve this with SQL only, you would have to look at the other answer using SQL function `MAX` in a sub-query and add raw queries in your Laravel code *(probably a little bit more efficient then rejecting non-matching)*.

However you can filter your collection after retrieval and reject the elements that doesn't match your criteria.

Assuming the variable `$q` is of type string and contains a status e.g. "manual", something like this should do the job (code not tested).

```
$leads = Lead::whereHas('statuses', function ($query) use ($q) {
    $query->where('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
})
->with('statuses')
->get()
->reject(function($element) use($q) {
    $lastStatus = $element->statuses[count($element->statuses)-1];
    return (strpos($lastStatus->description, $q) === false);
});
```

If you're column `description` should contain the exact string "manual" I would do it this way instead:

```
$leads = Lead::whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
    $query->where('description', 'manual');
})
->with('statuses')
->get()
->reject(function($element) {
    $lastStatus = $element->statuses[count($element->statuses)-1];
    return $lastStatus->description !== 'manual';
});
```

The `whereHas` method will not remove any relations like you need. The `whereHas` method will only say *"select the records that have one or more children that matches this criteria", however all of the children records will be accessible, even the once that doesn't matches your criteria, as long as the parent has one that matches.*

What you would like to say is *"select the records that have one or more children that matches this criteria (`whereHas`) THEN remove all parents where the last child record does not match the record I am looking for (`reject`)"*

**Edit: Updated code using `->with('statuses')` for improved performance.**

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention was that I want to paginate the result. How do I go about doing that along with the reject? ->get()->reject() seems to work fine, but ->paginate(10)->reject() doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have not used Laravel's pagination, however I think fetching records, then removing them can create some problems with pagination. I would suggest take a look at Kevin Bui's answer below (second solution). Define a relationship returning the last record only. That way you don't have to use `reject`, and you don't fetch unnecessary records like my answer will, and you can use pagination as normal.

Comment: This is definitely work, but not very performant. For each $lead object, you are running an extra query to the database.

Comment: That is true, however this can easily be solved by adding `->with('statuses')` resulting in one query only.

Comment: Fixed the code now for improved performance. Still, I think @KevinBui answer is the way to go. He deserves the correct answer on this one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have a great Laravel answer, but in case you end up going down the native query option, which you can then hydrate, here's a raw sql option... At the least, I hope it might help you visualise what you're trying to achieve.

```sql
CREATE TABLE leads (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `info` varchar(100) NULL default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE statuses (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `leads_id` int(11) null default null,
  `description` varchar(100) NULL default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `leads` (`info`) VALUES ('foo'), ('bar'), ('test');

INSERT INTO `statuses` (`leads_id`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'manual'),
(1, 'auto'),
(1, 'auto'),
(2, 'auto'),
(2, 'auto'),
(2, 'manual'),
(3, 'manual'),
(3, 'manual'),
(3, 'manual');

SELECT l.*
FROM statuses s 
JOIN leads l ON l.id = s.leads_id
WHERE s.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(s.id)
    FROM leads l
    JOIN statuses s ON s.leads_id = l.id
    GROUP BY l.id
)
AND s.description LIKE '%manual%'
```

Comment: This is the way to go for best efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to define a new relationship on the Lead table.

```
class Lead extends Model
{
    public function lastStatus()
    {
        return $this->statuses()->latest()->limit(1);
    }
}
```

This way, the final query can be a bit simpler.

```
$leads = Lead::whereHas(‘lastStatus’, function ($query) use ($q) {
    $query->where(‘description’, ‘LIKE’, $q);
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround, without testing the code I think this will work, giving OP the possibility to solve the problem with pure eloquent-functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. This hasOne relationship with a condition is pretty neat!

Comment: my statuses() relation in my Lead class is a 'belongsToMany' so wouldn't my lastStatus() be belongsTo instead of hasOne? Anyways, I've just tested this, but it throws an error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'leads.last_status_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `leads` where (exists (select * from `statuses` where `leads`.`last_status_id` = `statuses`.`id` and `description` LIKE %Manual%)))

Comment: @Nissen just copy-paste your `statuses()` function, rename it to `lastStatus()` and add `->latest();`.

Comment: if I add latest() all it does is reverse the collection, so it doesn't just take the last status, it still takes all the statuses, but in reverse

Comment: @Nissen ahh, I forgot that its a many to many relationship. I have updated my answer. I have not done this b4, but pls have a go.