# Querying the existence of an exact set of many to many relationship with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to make a query to find a Model that has an exact set of a many-to-many relationship.

For example, I have a Blog post that has many Tags. The tags can belongs to many blog posts.

How could I retrieve all blogs posts that have the tag #1, #2 and #3 without any other tag, only these 3, in an efficient manner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223533/laravel-wherehas-last-relation-is-manual/60223873#60223873

Comment: @AndrewLarsen Your answer was downvoted (sorry) since `whereIn()` matches _any_ of the values passed, not _all_ of them. This question is specifically asking for a method to query `Blog` for all records that have an association with `Tag` records with `id` 1, 2 **AND** 3. You would need multiple `->whereHas()`, one for each `Tag`, or similar. I don't think that answer does that either...

Comment: @TimLewis, you are correct. I deleted my answer and added the comment above for this reason.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen Ah I see it now; the answer illustrates how to do a `whereHas()`, then `reject()` to filter records to a subset. That approach would also work when adapted, but has the potential to not be very efficient, as multiple `Blog` records would be loaded into memory just to be filtered out.

Comment: @TimLewis this is also correct, which I also mention in that thread, and I refer to another answer in that thread that solves this in a more efficient way.

Comment: `If you would like to solve this with SQL only, you would have to look at the other answer using SQL function MAX in a sub-query and add raw queries in your Laravel code (probably a little bit more efficient then rejecting non-matching).`

Comment: @AndrewLarsen Heh, apparently I need to read the other answers on that page more  Ah well, still useful to have that information in the conversation for this question. It's also not a 1:1, since this one isn't using `MAX()` or looking for a "last" relationship, etc., but the idea still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First approach that comes to my mind is a `->whereHas()` for each Tag you want to find, something like:

```
$tagIds = [1, 2, 3];

$query = Blog::where(function ($query) use ($tagIds) {
  foreach ($tagIds as $tagId) {
    $query->whereHas('tags', function ($subQuery) use ($tagId) {
      return $subQuery->where('tags.id', $tagId); 
    });
  }
})->has('tags', '=', count($tagIds));

// Additional Clauses/Filters/Etc.

$blogs = $query->get();
```

This will execute an additional query for the Tags supplied (based on ID), and filter your `Blog` records to only those that match all supplied Tags.

Comment: OP specifies `How could I retrieve all blogs posts that have the tag #1, #2 and #3 without any other tag, only these 3, in an efficient manner?` this solution would match those that have these 3 tags but it doesn't take into consideration if the blog posts are associated with more then these 3 tags, so if one of them is associated with 4 tags, and 3 of them is correct we still get this blog. Why is this? Because you are only telling eloquent to get blogs that contains these tag ids, you are not saying anything about not getting those that have more then these.

Comment: Hmm you're right, this doesn't handle the other side of that requirement. That should be an easy modification, let me just set up a local sandbox to help test this.

Comment: Oh duh, `withCount('tags')->where('tags_count', 3)`, or `->has('tags', '=', 3)` 

Comment: Thank you for the callout; I've coded this before, but the requirement was to match _all_ supplied associated records instead of _any_, while this one is asking for _only_ the supplied records. Missed that 

Comment: No problem. Didn't look like you needed that sandbox after all. Good solve :)